# Packing properties into type object and return it as result of method

Tags: c#

I would like to create instance of type object in method, add to It two properties and return object as result of method.

```
public object method()
{
TypeOfClassA a;
int b;
if(method(out a, out b))
{
res = new {a=a, b=b};
}
return res;
}
```

Something like this

Comment: It looks like your code does exactly what you are describing. What is your question?

Comment: hm but at line where I wrote return says that I am using unassigned variable..how to have object with those properties after if is finished? hope you understand me

Comment: exactly thhe name doesnt exist in current context

Comment: Then you don't have a `object` class, you have some some kind of custom class, so go declare one or use the new value tuples in C# 7 to declare the type at the site of the function.

Comment: I prefer not to use tuples now. can you help me understand this as I though object class is only to be instansiated as class of all classes. how can I do that here ? i am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want `Tuple<T1, T2>`, then `dynamic` is your only choice.

```
public dynamic method()
{
    TypeOfClassA a;
    int b;
    if(method(out a, out b))
    {
        var res = new {a=a, b=b};
        return res;
    }

    return null; // You need to return something here. What happens if the if statement is not executed?
}
```

You can call `method` like this:

```
dynamic val = method();
Console.WriteLine(val.a); // or "val.b"
```

Comment: hm I got everything, except I have another error. I declared as variables 
`TypeOfClassa lastA TypeOfClassa a int lastB int b` then when created new object I am trying to assign `{lastA = a, lastB=b ` .. but it says lastA lastB are assigned but never used. How to make use of this values I will have after method call with out variables? hope you get me !

Comment: You don't need `lastA` and `lastB`. Remove them. They are just property names for your anonymous class. They are not variables! @makima89

Comment: thank you it works now, but If you would be kind to send me some link to read more about your last sentence, as I didnt really get it, to me looks natural to use new properties in newly created object and assign values which I took from the method. :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types @makima89

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the return statement. If you do not enter the `if-body`, the variable `res` is undeclared

```
public object method()
{
    TypeOfClassA a;
    int b;
    if(method(out a, out b))
    {
        res = new {a=a, b=b};
        return res;
    }

    return null;
}
```

In the adjusted snippet we only return `res`, if it was created. Otherwise, we return `null`.